# Jqgrid Not showing negative value perfectly while using RTL direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid for reporting. I have applied **direction :"rtl"** for that and its working perfectly but when negative value comes it not showing perfectly. see the image below.

[image]

In this image see the **Total Invoice Amount** and **Total Cash Sales** column. both have value -11,828 and total should be -9,013.57 at the bottom. But it looks weird.

Comment: Seems like a bug as '-' is not considered as numerical sign. Maybe forcing float parsing could help when you are setting cell's value.

Comment: You system language is arabic so thats it look werid.